# Zxing - Generating custom colored qr codes

Tags: zxing

I'm using the zxing javase client library along with the zxing core library to generate QR codes from URLs in a java application. I need to generate custom colored QR codes and looking at the javadocs, using MatrixToImageConfig with MatrixToImageWriter (both in the javase package) seems to be an ideal solution. However, the latest version of zxing(2.0) that I found on the downloads page doesn't have any class named MatrixToImageConfig.

The file is present in the latest code that I downloaded from subversion. Has this been feature been released yet ? If no, is there some other way to achieve this using zxing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it was added after 2.0. It is in Subversion; you can just use the code / JAR from Subversion or use 2.1-SNAPSHOT in Maven.